# slf4j Error in deployement with tomcat 7

Tags: spring, jsf, tomcat, jakarta-ee

Hi guys I have an application developed with jsf, spring and hibernate.
The app is deployed with jboss as7 normally without any problem,
but when I change the server to tomcat 7,
I get this error:

GRAVE: Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé (context initialized) à l'instance de classe d'écoute (listener) org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.error(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:225)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:227)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5068)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5584)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1572)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1562)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

juin 07, 2016 10:48:45 AM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFOS: Initialisation de Mojarra 2.2.12 ( 20150720-0848 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.12@14885) pour le contexte

Comment: which language is this.. how could i understand this...

Comment: seems like French to me.

Comment: thanks bro x),my tomcat configured with french langage

Answer (score 0):

`SLF4J` is just an interface to logging API calls. During run time it will use any available logging framework (like `log4j`, `commons-logging` etc.) in the `classpath` as the implementation.

It looks when you use tomcat,
its not able to find any implementation.
Can you try including `log4j.jar` and `logback` jars in your lib folder and see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: logback is bettern than log4j.  consider logback.

Comment: thanks Dayalan, I use maven project and I alreddy put log4j in my dependencies!!!